# El navegador me muestra el código php

Tags: php

He tratado de abrir una página web con PHP pero en vez de ejecutarse el código PHP, el navegador me muestra el contenido del código.

Uso wampp y ahí está encendido el apache y MySQL.
Gracias al que pueda ayudarme

Comment: El archivo tiene que tener terminación `.php`, por ejemplo "index.php" en vez de "index.html".

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tienes mal configurado Apache2 así que vas a tener que verificar algunas cosas.

- Lo básico es que tengas instalado y activo el módulo de php.
- Que el archivo que ejecutas tenga extensión `.php`.
- Que uses `<?php` en vez de `<?`, este último está desabilitado por defecto.
- Mira también que tengas en tu archivo de configuración `httpd.conf` (puede variar el nombre del archivo según tu sistema operativo) tengas la línea `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

;-)